# asp.net MVC - AJAX model to controller

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to pass my view Model to the controller, using ajax, without 'rebuilding' the object?

I have my view:

```
@using Project.Models
@model InfoFormulaireEnqueteModele


@section Style{
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />}


@section Scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/autocomplete")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/timeentry")

<script type="text/javascript">
    var $status = $('#status'),
        $commentBox = $('#commentBox'),
        timeoutId;
    var model = @Model;  //<- something's wrong here

  $commentBox.keypress(function () {
    $status.attr('class', 'pending').text('changes pending');

    // If a timer was already started, clear it.
    if (timeoutId) clearTimeout(timeoutId);

    var r = '';
    // Set timer that will save comment when it fires.
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        var test = $('#commentBox').val();
        // Make ajax call to save data.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            url: '/Enquete/IndexPartial/',
            contentType: "application/json"
        }).done(function (res) {
            $("#SomeDivToShowTheResult").html(res);
        });
        $status.attr('class', 'saved').text('changes saved');
    }, 1000);
    return r;
 });

</script>
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult IndexPartial(InfoFormulaireEnqueteModele m)
    {
        return PartialView("_IndexPartial", m);
    }
```

I am able to reach my controller, but my model (m) has only null values once in the controller.. The values were set in the controller before being sent to the view.

Comment: where r u setting vales when you send to controller .  you need to set vales then use send back . please note u r using post  so you need to send json values . ig you print model it will be null if i m not wrong .

Comment: can you tell print this in console JSON.stringify(model)

Comment: What are you attempting to do here? Why would you want to pass back the original unchanged model to the server?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am calling this for an autosave feature..it will be called only after the user has stop editing a field for 1s (for now it's only applied for #commentBox but if I can make it work I will apply this to the entire form).

Comment: `@Model` is server side code - its the model that you initially sent to the client. And to send it back you would need to use `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model));` but that would be pointless. If your want the values of your inputs then its `data: { commentBox: $('#commentBox').val() }` or to include all form controls - `data: $('form').serialize(),` (and remove the `contentType` option)

Comment: But unless your saving this to a temporary database, do not do this. Never override a users data records unless the user has submitted the form.

Answer (score 0):

In your action method speciy [FromBody] as below

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult IndexPartial([FromBody] InfoFormulaireEnqueteModele m)
{
  return PartialView("_IndexPartial", m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model));
```

That's how you convert your model to json and pass it to js