# redirect view after timeout

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a view Index, called from Index Action inside EnqueteController, which has all my javascript code in it. This view RenderPartial a form, _EnqueteForm which has all my form inputs. In my javascript section (in Index) I have the following:

```
@section Scripts{

<script type="text/javascript">

var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 10; //seconds
var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
document.onclick = function () {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
document.onmousemove = function () {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
document.onkeypress = function () {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);

function CheckIdleTime() {
    _idleSecondsCounter++;
    if (oPanel)
        oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter) + "";
    if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '/Enquete/Inactive',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
        });
    }
}
```

}

After 10 seconds of inactivity, it's calling Inactive action from Enquete Controller.

This action looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Inactive([System.Web.Http.FromBody] InfoFormulaireEnqueteModele m)
    {
        int userId = this.UserId();

        LibraryEnquete.EnregistrerFormulaire(m, userId);
        TransitionEtatPrecedent(m.HevEvenementID, userId);
        return View("Logout");
    }
```

My action is called correctly after 10s and it's calling LibraryEnquete.EnrigistrerFormulaire and also TransitionEtatPrecedent. But my problems are:

1) It wont change to the 'Logout' view

2) For some reason, my Inactive method is called from other page?! After one call, I stop the application and once I restart it, from the main page (which is not the EnqueteController Index page), it's calling the Inactive method like 20 times until I stop the application

Comment: You not doing anything in the ajax success callback (e.g. updating the DOM with the view that your method returns). But it sounds like you want to redirect to another view (ajax calls never redirect - the whole point is to stay on the same page)

Comment: Do you know how my Inactive method could be call again and again from a different controller's action's view?

Comment: Sorry, its really unclear what your trying to do here. What do your `LibraryEnquete.EnregistrerFormulaire()` and `TransitionEtatPrecedent()` methods do. And why are you calling a method that does something just because the page has been inactive? (this seems related to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42539216/asp-net-mvc-ajax-model-to-controller) where you were trying to save data without the users knowledge - do not do that!)

Comment: I am implementing a really long form. Previously I was trying to save a draft of it (which is working now, thanks!) but now, if the form is inactive for 2 hours (it's 10 seconds now for testing purpose), I want to save the form (EnregistrerFormulaire) and to set the form state to it's previous state (like a state machine defining when the form is open and by whom and what kind of action can be done on the form)

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls do not handle redirect responses (http status code 3xx).

By returning the view to an ajax call, you are just getting the view rendered as string in the ajax success event handler.

In order for the browser to render the logout view, you can just proceed to submit the form without using ajax:

```
if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
    $('form').submit();
}
```

If the form's action it's not poiting to `/Enquete/Inactive`, you can change the action before submiting the form:

```
if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
    $('form').prop('action', '/Enquete/Inactive');
    $('form').submit();
}
```